# How do you create a container with volume via service?

Tags: java, docker

So...
I managed to pull an image from docker hub and deployed a service and started a container...
but how can I bind a volume to an container when it is created?

```
     dockerClient.pullImageCmd(image).withTag(tag)
                .exec(new PullImageResultCallback());
 ServiceSpec serviceSpec = new ServiceSpec()
                .withMode(new ServiceModeConfig()
                        .withReplicated(new ServiceReplicatedModeOptions()
                                .withReplicas(1)))
                .withName(trname) 
                .withTaskTemplate(new TaskSpec()
                        .withContainerSpec(new ContainerSpec()
                                .withImage(image)));  
        String serviceId = dockerClient.createServiceCmd(serviceSpec).exec().getId();
```

Comment: Which Docker client library are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java Docker API Client

Comment: Then check autocompletion in various places, there should be a withVolume method somewhere

Comment: I can only find withMounts under ContainerSpec() ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out...

```
.withContainerSpec(new ContainerSpec()
                                .withMounts(Collections.singletonList(new Mount()
                                        .withType(MountType.BIND)
                                        .withSource("/var/run/docker.sock")
                                        .withTarget("/var/run/docker.sock")))
```